# Vim regex with metacharacters inside bracket

Tags: regex, vim

How can you search for a metacharacter or another character in a vim regular expression?

Example: (I would like this to match the metacharacter '\w' or the character '-' 1 or more times

```
[-\w]\+
```

But that regex does not work like I would hope it would. It only matches -, w and . I have tried to escape the '\' but that doesn't work.

I have looked through the vim documentation, but there is no example of this.

Comment: Also as a side note, I know that I could do something like [-a-zA-Z]\+. I am not looking for that solution. I am interested in meta-characters inside brackets.

Comment: +1 for asking a question I have often pondered!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside a collection, you have to use special character classes. The following expression is equivalent to yours:

```
[-_[:alnum:]]\+
```

Check `:h [:alnum:]` (and subsequent lines) for a complete list on supported classes.

Comment: If you're dealing with ASCII, yes, `[-_A-Za-z]` is just easier.

Comment: The pattern you give is *not* equivalent to one asked in the question.  The equivalent is `[-_[:alnum:]]\+` (see `:h \w` and `:h alpha`).

Comment: Sorry @ib , and thanks for pointing it out. Indeed I wrote the correct class when referring to help but misplaced the former.

Answer (score 4):

```
\%(\w\|-\)*
```

Using `\%(` group so nothing is captured. `\|` for alternation between `\w` and `-`

or with very magic, with `\v`

```
\v%(\w|-)*
```

Comment: This is very helpful, however it does not have the metacharacter inside the bracket.

Comment: The two are equivalent. e.g. `\%(a\|b\|c\)\+` is the same as `[abc]\+`. Now if you said you need to use `[^...]` that would be something else entirely. My thought is use whatever is equivalent and saves you typing and/or brain power.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [eregex.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3282) which translates from PCRE to Vim's syntax, expanding `[\w]` to `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, among many other thing that it does. It takes [over a thousand lines of vim to achieve that translation](https://github.com/othree/eregex.vim/blob/master/plugin/eregex.vim)!