# Vim regex to search and highlight words with hyphens in it

Tags: vim

I have a JSON file, and it has double quotes around keys and values. I want to remove double quotes from the keys(I know it would be invalid JSON, but still trying something). to do so I used this regex

```
:%s/"\(\w*\)":/\1:
```

But now the issue is that some of the keys have hyphen(maybe multiple) in them. The aforementioned solution won't work anymore. It only selects the keys that don't have hyphens. I tried to find a solution for this, but couldn't find anything concrete. Would be very helpful if you could help a little.

Comment: Try `:%s/"\([a-zA-Z0-9-]*\)":/\1:/g`, add any character you want after last '-' if you want to allow more exception.

Comment: thanks, @samabcde. One small question tho, would `\w` be good instead of [a-zA-Z] if I know that there would be no digits?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341322/vim-regex-with-metacharacters-inside-bracket) about your question.